# Empty nvidia-settings after install v. 331.67 driver on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I've followed [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-nvidia-driver-331-67-ubuntu1404/) tutorial (with the following adjustments below) to install v. 331.67 nVidia driver. But get nvidia-settings (NVIDIA X Server Settings) empty...

Then, before restart the PC, I make a xorg.conf in the nvidia-settings.

The driver make Unity don't start right. So I installed nvidia-331-updates via apt-get and restarted the PC again.

After that, the Unity works fine. But the nvidia-settings gets almost empty...

[image: Empty nvidia-settings]

Can someone help !?

Comment: Made it work? I have the same problem...

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/496116/189064

Answer (score 5):

You installed the driver from ubuntu repositories over a driver you manually installed.

Follow that tutorial to uninstall that driver.

Then remove nvidia-updates with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-331-updates nvidia-settings`.

Reinstall Nvidia current driver with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings`

Comment: Is there any safe way to manually install (from the *.run) nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 without crashing Unity !?

Comment: @Victoralm I have done this and it worked until I updated kernel.

Comment: Didn't help in my case :\