# Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia-settings is empty

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-settings

I installed nvidia driver 331-updates from the additional drivers tab but after open the nvidia-settings there are only two options(Application Profiles and nvidia-settings Configuration same as in this picture: 
[image]

Try to run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` in the terminal but says command not found. i also checked my xconfig file and it is empty, so possibly i should have to create it, but I can't. Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Same problem here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451405/empty-nvidia-settings-after-install-v-331-67-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty nvidia-settings after install v. 331.67 driver on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451405/empty-nvidia-settings-after-install-v-331-67-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04)