# Detect (apparently) manually installed driver Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have the same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451405/empty-nvidia-settings-after-install-v-331-67-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04) and the solution is saying that I manually installed a driver and this causes the problem. Great! But **how do I detect said driver (and deinstall it)?**

I tried various ideas from the internet:

```
$> nvidia-settings -q NvidiaDriverVersion

ERROR: Error resolving target specification '' (No targets match target specification), specified in query 'NvidiaDriverVersion'.

$> grep -i "x driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
   ""

$> lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 0170
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 0170
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

If anybody wonders - I installed `nvidia-settings` separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output shows something like :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Now you can see that the NVIDIA drivers are in use -> `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`

To uninstall the drivers execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

This removes the `nvidia-settings` application as well.

Comment: apparently I did not have any drivers installed. I'll try installing nvidia current now and see where it might leed

Comment: I did deinstalled, rebooted and installed nvidia-current but the output of your command (as given in the last edit) still stays the same - no Kernel driver listed.

Comment: @Sim : nvidia-current are drivers for older NVIDIA graphics adapters from the GEFORCE 8x and 9x series, in case you have a newer one from the GEFORCE 400 - 900 series you have to install nvidia-352 ! :)