# Ubuntu 14.04 Dual graphics Nvidia doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I used to be able to switch to Nvidia by going to software sources. Now when I click the driver for my graphics card it downloads, turns green and it looks like its using the correct driver but when I go to system details it says its using my Intel graphics. The performance is accordingly average...
But I have gfx card with 2G of dedicated memory!
Is there a way I can do this? Possibly something in grub? Or even better: graphics card switching without need for reboot? Something like: https://gfx.io/?

Answer (score 4):

If you have **nvidia prime** installed just go to nvidia x server settings and choose it in prime profile (you need to relog to apply the changes).
[image: Nvidia prime]

**To install prime:**

First make sure bumblebee not installed! Or just remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
```

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

You can also install prime-indicator for easier switching.
[image: Prime indicator]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

If you prefer to use **bumblebee**/have it installed you have to run the application with a command to use the video card (advantage: you don't need to relog).

```
optirun <program-name>
```

To install bumblebee make sure you remove prime!
More info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: for some reason **this** happens: [link](http://imgur.com/3o0SbN6)

Comment: I recommend you to remove all and re-install:

      `sudo apt-get purge bumblebee* nvidia*`

Then install: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime`

Comment: Also go to settings -> Software & Updates -> Additonal drivers -> Choose "using nvidia binary driver ... (prop, tested)"

Comment: I reinstalled exactly as you said and this is a screenshot of my "additional drivers" list http://imgur.com/e64JFXN but i still get that blank error :/

Comment: I found this but not sure which solution is best for me... Any advice? Or should i try them all? http://askubuntu.com/questions/450154/nvidia-331-nvidia-settings-prime-profile-switching-error

Comment: I tried everything on the list except reinstalling ubuntu :( I dont want to reinstall ubuntu _AGAIN_ ! :( Any ideas @guyromb ?

Comment: @EliášBauer Do you have Nvidia Optimus enabled in the BIOS of your computer?

Comment: @Sean how do i do that?

Comment: @EliášBauer To entire the BIOS you need to start with the computer off then hold a certain ket down as the boot starts. The key differs  by manufacturer, `F1` or `DEL` are often used, it should say on your screen at boot time. In the BIOS look for a graphics category to find the Optimus setting.

Comment: @Sean There is no such option in my bios :/

Comment: In the end i reinstalled a frech copy of ubuntu GNOME 15.10 and everything works perfectly