# high temperature after update to 16.04 LTS- Nvidia Optimus

Tags: drivers, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I recently updated from Ubuntu 14 to 16.04 LTS. Since that according to 'coretemp' the temperature reaches 80 to 85°C a few minutes after i started my computer.
My GPU is a Nvidia Geforce GT 540M. I had temperatureproblems like that before the update, but using bumblebee and cpufreq made it possible to keep it between 55 and 70°C. 
As that didn't work anymore after the update i switched to a not propriatery driver, uninstalled bumblebee and installed prime.
But somehow this isn't working..

```
$ sudo prime-select intel
Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'mesa']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Error: the installed packages do not support PRIME
Error: intel mode can't be enabled
```

Comment: Nvidia driver is not installed.

Comment: so what am i supposed to do? install the one from the nvidia homepage? i thought it wouldn't work with prime because its somehow protected..

Comment: Not from Nvidia page, but a way a wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt install nvidia-361
```

and reboot. If UEFI is used, disable Secure Boot.

To reduce heating you can switch to the integrated adapter by

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

then log off or reboot.

Comment: You need to disable Secure Boot to use proprietary drivers.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/762255/167850

Comment: I installed it and restarted without disabling the secure Boot, because i didn't remember my Bios unlock Password. After i restarted The Gryphius didn't Funktion wall anymore. I Tried ' sudo prime-select Intel' and got an Output that was different form The one before(longer).. The after half a minute The Screen Turner Black.. i was not able to do anything so I turned it of using the power button..

Comment: restarted again now. 'sudo prime-select' works but the cpu temperature ist still staying between 68 and 85°C..

Comment: i was able to enter my bios somehow now. i doesn't look like i have a secure boot option.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea how i can reduce the temperature more?

Comment: I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try:</s>

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee* nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime prime-indicator
```

And reboot. It will uninstall any nvidia and bumblebee packages you have and will install older driver with nvidia settings panel and prime indicator. Works for my GT650M. Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** Turn off web browser and programs that you use, then check `top` if your computer uses too much CPU in idle. Check Psensor for accurate temperature measurements. If it is overheating in idle (let's say <5% CPU), check whether you are using Intel or nVidia graphics by running `glxgears`. On Intel you should have around 60FPS, same as your screen refresh rate. nVidia renders much more - my GT650M shows few thousand FPS, so should yours. Also, check [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610418/ubuntu-14-04-dual-graphics-nvidia-doesnt-work), where I found first reply working great.
Also, when was your exhaust and fan cleaned? I clean them once a year and also change thermal paste.

Good luck, mate.

Comment: switching to intel was possible before.. i did what you suggested- only the package prime- indicator was not found. Now prime seems to be gone totally and temperatures are between 82 and 99°C .. i'll go back to nvidia-361

Comment: how can i switch my terminal to english so i can post the code here?

Comment: See [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/264283/switch-command-output-language-from-native-language-to-english)

Comment: ok everything is in english now and i'm using the nvidia-361 aigain.. prime seems to be working but the temperatures still go up to arround 85° very quickly as soon as i start surfing or use libre office or anything else.

Comment: Is Ubuntu 16.04 your only OS? Have you checked `top` command to see CPU usage?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu is my only one right now..

Comment: I updated my reply. Hope it will help.

Comment: monitor refresh rat is 60.something ..

Comment: in idle, the temperature stays around 55°C. I just updated my bios. i think that helped.. as soon as i get "active" on the laptop using several programms, surfing and so on- temperature climbs up to around 75°C very quickly. It didn't reach 85 or even 95°C since the biosupdate. Could that be normal/ acceptable? I cleaned my fan about two years ago.. but didn't change thermal paste. I guess that would be quite wise. I'm planing to do it since a long time. But openig my Laptop appeared as not that simpel so i didn't get it done yet.

Comment: What is your laptop model and how old is it? Better temperatures after BIOS update can be acceptable, maybe there was a problem with your BIOS firmware. Well, after two years I would reccomend to clean fan and exhaust with compressed air and change thermal paste. I use Arctic Silver V thermal paste and have less than 70°C on 100% CPU usage (i5-3210M).

Comment: Sounds good! My Laptop is a Acer Aspire 5057G. I bought it five years ago i think.. Where did you get the compressed air?

Comment: I used a compressor to clear exhaust and fan. Just be careful when blowing into fan, it can spin at high RPM.

Answer (score 0):

```
    top - 14:14:19 up  1:01,  1 user,  load average: 1,17, 1,06, 0,99
    Tasks: 258 total,   1 running, 257 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
    %Cpu(s): 11,9 us,  2,5 sy,  0,0 ni, 85,2 id,  0,2 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,2         si,  0,0 st
    KiB Mem :  8024888 total,  4210752 free,  1742944 used, 2071192         buff/cache
    KiB Swap:  8235004 total,  8235004 free,        0 used.  5650252 avail Mem
```